# WPF: How do I obtain the size of the visible portion of a TextBox in a TreeView (see image)?

Tags: .net, wpf

Is there a way to get the size of the visible portion of a WPF UI control, say a TextBox, in a TreeView?

For example, in this image I would want the size of the viewable part of the pinkish TextBox:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this duplicated?

[How do I get the size of the visible part of a WPF usercontrol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112533/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-the-visible-part-of-a-wpf-usercontrol)

Anyway: You can do it via [IScrollInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo.aspx)

Comment: 1- Where is the answer to _my_ question in the question you linked? and 2- how do I use IScrollInfo to get what I want?

Comment: So how do I use IScrollInfo to get the size of the displayed part of the textbox?

Comment: ViewportHeight & ViewportWidth will give you the ViewPort size (visible size). Those are properties of the IScrollInfo.